# A* Pathfinding Data Structure

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

I'm currently trying to follow the current A* pseudocode (from Wikipedia) to write my A* algorithm:

```
function A*(start,goal)
    closedset := the empty set    // The set of nodes already evaluated.
    openset := {start}    // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated, initially containing the start node
    came_from := the empty map    // The map of navigated nodes.

    g_score[start] := 0    // Cost from start along best known path.
    // Estimated total cost from start to goal through y.
    f_score[start] := g_score[start] + heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

    while openset is not empty
        current := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
        if current = goal
            return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)

        remove current from openset
        add current to closedset
        for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)
            if neighbor in closedset
                continue
            tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + dist_between(current,neighbor)

            if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor] 
                came_from[neighbor] := current
                g_score[neighbor] := tentative_g_score
                f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
                if neighbor not in openset
                    add neighbor to openset

    return failure

function reconstruct_path(came_from,current)
    total_path := [current]
    while current in came_from:
        current := came_from[current]
        total_path.append(current)
    return total_path
```

I'm using a PriorityQueue for the openset and closedset each, however I'm unsure what to use for the "came_from" map of navigated nodes. Does it matter? Should I use a Priority Queue as well? Or will a simple List do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the C# Dictionary Data Structure in the end, and it's worked well, if anyone is interested.